# Installing stone ledger in standing shower

Tags: bathroom, shower, backsplash

Hey all I'm currently in the middle of remodeling my bathroom and I was considering installing this [stone ledger](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MSI-Alaska-Gray-Ledger-Panel-6-in-x-24-in-Textured-Marble-Wall-Tile-1-sq-ft-Each-LPNLMALAGRY624/207041759?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_006_FLR_WLL_TILE-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-2996251-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_WLL_TILE_PMax_G&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_006_FLR_WLL_TILE-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-2996251-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_WLL_TILE_PMax_G-71700000103148691--&gbraid=0AAAAADq61Uc7G1PyJ2h1rFTSAeEFX-3D6&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3OrNiZaUgAMVqM7jBx3b4gmcEAQYAiABEgLoWPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) (*Home Depot link*) as a backsplash for my standing shower.

I've seen this used for fire places as well as backsplashes for tubs but not for a standing shower. My two concern is if it is prone to mold buildup as well as cleaning. The product details mention that it's for outdoor and indoor use so I'm assuming it's good. As for cleaning would spraying some cleaning solution and brushing it be sufficient?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Advice: Don't.

It is difficult to clean mold, mineral deposits and soap scum from shower and bath areas, even when they are made from smooth, hard materials like an enamel bathtub or glazed porcelain tiles.

It must be a lot more difficult to clean them from a rough natural stone surface like this.  I have never tried and I would not want to.

I also think a rough surface like this would be inappropriate for a shower because touching it accidentally with elbows or other body parts would be painful.

Comment: That was my first thought too...mold.

Answer (score 0):

From the HD web site's product description:

> Natural stones may be characterized by dry seams and pits that are often filled. *The filling can work its way out and it may be necessary to refill these voids as part of a normal maintenance procedure*.
> <sup>Emphasis added</sup>

While that may work great for a tub surround that gets *splashed* that doesn't sound like a winner for a shower surround that gets *soaked* every day.

Answer (score 0):

Those tiles are not made to be grouted after install.  Therefore they offer no waterproofing and are not intended for use in a shower.